# Group by and perform a multiple operation to another array and push to a new array

Tags: javascript

I want to push a value to a new array by doing multiple operations to the value of another object array, by grouping with some `key`.

I have the array as:

```
var newArray = [{ltd: "Cpt", stdSquare: "0.35", error: "0.65"},
 {ltd: "Cpt", stdSquare: "0.16", error: "0.84"},
 {ltd: "Ant", stdSquare: "0.21", error: "0.79"},
 {ltd: "Ant", stdSquare: "0.79", error: "0.21"}];
```

Here in this below reduces function I want to sum the value of `stdSquare` and push to the `results` array, by grouping with the `ltd`.

But this is giving me an error as:

> Uncaught TypeError: map.get is not a function

```
var results = [];
const sums = [
  ...newArray.reduce(
    (map, item) => {

      const { ltd: key, stdSquare } = item;

      let sumOfstdSquare = 0;
      const prev = map.get(key);
              
        sumOfstdSquare += stdSquare;
       
        results.push({ltd, sumOfstdSquare});
 
      
      return results
    },
    new Map()
  ).values()
]
```

Desired output:

```
[
  {ltd:"Cpt", sumOfstdSquare: 0.51},
  {ltd:"Ant", sumOfstdSquare: 1.00}
]
```

Comment: seems to be wrong use of reduce. `map.get is not a function` because you are returning `results` inside the reduce function which is an array not a map and doesn't have the `.get` method

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to:

- sum all stdSquare
- group by ltd

Here is the example:
In this answer i don’t modify the origin, i create a new array `grouped`

If you want to make the origin to point to the result jusr use `newArray = [...groupd];`

```js
var newArray = [
 {ltd: "Cpt", stdSquare: "0.35", error: "0.65"},
 {ltd: "Cpt", stdSquare: "0.16", error: "0.84"},
 {ltd: "Ant", stdSquare: "0.21", error: "0.79"},
 {ltd: "Ant", stdSquare: "0.79", error: "0.21"}];
 
 const grouped = newArray.reduce((ret, val) => {
  const ltd = val.ltd
  const index = ret.findIndex(item=>item.ltd == ltd)
  if(index == -1) {
    return [...ret, {ltd: val.ltd, stdSquare: parseFloat(val.stdSquare)}]
  }
  else {
   const newItem = {ltd: val.ltd,stdSquare: parseFloat(val.stdSquare) + ret[index].stdSquare};
   ret.splice(index, 1, newItem)
   return ret
  }
  
 },
 [])
 
 console.log(grouped)
```

Comment: this doesn't seem to work, it's just printing what's on the input...I want to group by with `ltd` and sum the result, in a single array.

Comment: I guess I miss something here.. the code returns a group map and a sum. Can you add your desired output?

Comment: I have modified my post with the desired output, to show the sample but I could have any number of items returned from the reduced functions.